# ansible user variable overwritten by local machine user

Tags: ssh, users, ansible

so I am getting ansible setup and have a host configuration successfully setup via my ansible_hosts file:

```
104.236.59.171  ansible_connection=ssh  ansible_user=root
```

checking the configuration status of the hosts I get:

`104.236.59.171 | success >> {
    "var": {
        "hostvars['104.236.xx.xxx']": {
            "ansible_connection": "ssh", 
            "ansible_user": "root", 
            "group_names": [
                "ungrouped"
            ], 
            "inventory_hostname": "104.236.xx.xxx", 
            "inventory_hostname_short": "104"
        }
    }
}`

However, the user/name on my local machine takes precedence over the `ansible_user` variable which needs to be used for successful login.

I can override this with the `-u` option in my ansible commands, but when I have more than one different users on multiple server instances  and I am iterating over all of them, that will not be an option.

How do I go about overriding the default user obtained from my local machine?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please show your ansible code.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the slow response. Shown!

Answer (score 1):

Check the Ansible documentation on [Variable Precedence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

If you provide `ansible_user` variable with the `-u` parameter it will always overwrite every other variable definition.

As `inventory vars` is nearly at the top of the linked list you need to check for variable definition on the other levels. I would check with `grep` for other variable definitions and remove those.